# shouldn't norm.ppf() method only give positive output?

Tags: scipy, normal-distribution

I am learning online Udemy course for finance.
the author use .ppf() in one of his monte carlo simulation to simulate stock daily return.

my understand is .ppf (percentage point function )shows the distance to the mean given a certain percentage. and it is always positive. Normal distribution is always symmetric, in reality there are two values +- (output), but ppf() just show the absolute distance.

to my surprise the code give positive and negative outputs, can somebody help me is there something wrong with my understanding of statistic, or is there some specification of ppf() method I do not know? I anyway didn't find documentation with explanation of how ppf() method works. thank you !

the code is simple

norm.ppf(np.random.rand(10, 2))

Answer (score 1):

The `ppf` method is the inverse of the [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function).  It is also known as the [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function).

You said "and it is always positive", but that is not correct.  It will return values from the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of the distribution, which for the normal distribution is the entire real line.

The expression `norm.ppf(np.random.rand(10, 2))` generates random samples from the standard normal distribution, using the [inverse transform method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).  Instead of using that expression, you could simply call the `rvs` method: `norm.rvs(size=(10, 2))`.

Comment: Hello Warren; I have check again. random.rand() documentation. numpy.random.rand(d0, d1, ..., dn)
Random values in a given shape.

Create an array of the given shape and propagate it with random samples from a uniform distribution over [0, 1). so it generate from uniform distribution and only give positive values, values are not from standard normal distribution .

Comment: Yes, the values generated by `rand()` are from a uniform distribution over the unit interval.  These values are passed to `norm.ppf()` to generate samples from the normal distribution.  That is exactly the "inverse transform method".  Take another look at [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling#The_method) of the link I gave in my answer.